# writing text file on catch exception with IIS in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to write text file and add record in database while exception occur in application. Both functionality working locally but when I published my code to IIS functionality was not working. So do I need to change any IIS setting or do I need to do something else.

I did

I tried to write text file and add record in database while exception occur in application. Both functionality working locally but when I published my code to IIS functionality was not working. So do I need to change any IIS setting or do I need to do something else.

```
try{}
catch (Exception ex) {
   username='test';
   linenum=10;
   return RedirectToError(ex.ToString(), "Createpage", "Home", "HttpGet", linenum, "Create Lot", username);
}

public ActionResult Error()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult RedirectToError(string sExceptionName, string sEventName, string sControlName, string methodType, int nErrorLineNo, string sFormName, string username)
{
  Server.ClearError();
  //string username = Session["username"].ToString();
  DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
  ERROR_LOG log = new ERROR_LOG();
  log.CONTROLNAME = sControlName;
  log.METHODNAME = sEventName;
  log.METHODTYPE = methodType;
  log.FORMNAME = sFormName;
  log.Errortext = sExceptionName;
  log.LINE_NO = nErrorLineNo;
  log.USERNAME = username;
  log.ERRORDATE = DateTime.Now;
  Session["sExceptionName"] = "Exception:" + sExceptionName + "
  line:" + nErrorLineNo + "
  UserName:" + username;
  db.ERROR_LOG.Add(log);
  db.SaveChanges();

  return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors? What do the Window's log show? Have you set the proper permissions in the file system? Which part of your application are you logging this -- show us some code so we're not guessing.

Comment: No Jasen, that is my problem, because locally working perfectly and after publish if any exception occur it is redirecting error page but not saving record to database. so my code is like try { } catch { code for add record to database with all column }

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't have the code in it.

Comment: I added code so look an that one, i know code is perfect but iis need some permission or some other thing

Comment: If you put your `RedirectToError` method body in a try...catch you could write the error message to a file somewhere that IIS_IUSRS has write permission to see what is going wrong with the attempt to write to the database.